# Drawing commutative diagram in tex

Tags: diagrams

I want to draw this digram below in Latex and thank you .[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on.

Comment: Googling 'latex commutative diagram' (and then 'latex commutative diagram 3d') led to [Commutative Diagrams with XY-pic II](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/blaga/blaga.pdf). Section 4 shows a similar diagram with lots of explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to learn `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
A' \arrow[rr,"f'"] \arrow[dr,swap,"a"] \arrow[dd,swap,"g'"] &&
  B' \arrow[dd,swap,"h'" near start] \arrow[dr,"b"] \\
& A \arrow[rr,crossing over,"f" near start] &&
  B \arrow[dd,"h"] \\
C' \arrow[rr,"k'" near end] \arrow[dr,swap,"c"] && D' \arrow[dr,swap,"d"] \\
& C \arrow[rr,"k"] \arrow[uu,<-,crossing over,"g" near end]&& D
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

The only trick is to draw the "g" arrow later (and in the opposite direction), so that it can properly cross over the "k'" arrow that would be drawn later if the "g" arrow started from "A" instead of "C".

[image]