# What about Kuvio for making diagrams?

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, miktex

Kuvio (Finnish for 'pattern') seems to be a very general tool for diagram making.

- Which are the major disadvantages?
- Why isn't it used more often (only *one* Q/A on the site seems to mention it)?
- Can it be used in papers sent to mathematical journals?

[About Kuvio and other packages on diagrams](http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question tends to be very broad and provoke opinion-based answers, besides that -- is it connected to (La)TeX at all?

Comment: note that this would prevent it being included in texlive http://www.ctan.org/license/other-nonfree

Comment: The package seems to be a bit outdated. If you want to use postscript to *draw* stuff, use `PSTricks`. An alternative would be TikZ, of course. Advantage of those: actively maintained, large userbase.

Comment: The package cannot be in free software distributions because of its license, so it requires manual installation. It has been undeveloped for 18 years. Other packages such as Xy-pic and `tikz-cd` work with all engines (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`), while Kuvio requires `latex` (with `dvips` and `ps2pdf`). The more recent packages are far more powerful. Does this list suffice?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but kuvio and amscd are the only packages that works for me and my Miktex/Vista. I would love to have tikz but I can't make it work. I may harass the site with that question later...

Comment: @Lehs You should update your TeX distribution. I believe that MiKTeX 2.9 runs on Vista.

Comment: @egreg: I have MiKTeX 2.9.5105 but there is at least a file named tikzlibraryqoutes.code.tex is reported missing.

Comment: @Lehs Are you able to run the code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199186/4427 ?

Comment: @egreg: No! It gives the message report I wrote above.

Comment: @Lehs: You seem to have a corrupted or incomplete MikTeX installation

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: OK! I try to uninstall and reinstall. Could there be something missing on my system that interfere with the installation?

Comment: @Lehs: Sorry, I can't answer that, since I do not use MikTeX at all (I am Linux addict ;-) ), besides that, I can't look into your system ;-)

Comment: @Lehs: For me, `tikz-cd` works fine on MikTeX 2.9, Windows 7. You also can use the `psmatrix` environment, from `pst-node`. You can compile pstricks code with `pdflatex` now, if you launch it with the `--enable-write18` switch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated TeX-Distribution, an outdated package, and mainly opinion based.